# How can I ignore spaces when applying a git stash?

Tags: git, git-stash

I have some modifications in a git stash, and I would like to apply them using `git stash pop` or `git stash apply`. But I have changed some indentation in the files that the stash changes, and when I try to apply the stash, I get a bunch of merge conflicts. Is there a way to ignore whitespace while applying the stash, similar to the `-Xignore-all-space` option for `git merge`?

I tried `git stash apply -Xignore-all-space stash@{2}` and it told me `` error: unknown switch `X' ``.

Comment: IMHO, even if you *could* do what you wanted, I'd still prefer to convert the stash into a commit like [torek suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69018739/184546) because in general, many things are easier in Git when working with commits, including recovering from errors or mind changes.

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to do this with `git stash`.  Use the full Git tool suite.

OK, but you already have a stash.  Fortunately there's a really easy way to *convert* the stash to a temporary branch, using `git stash branch`:

```
git status    # make sure all is clean; if not, commit or stash
```

then:

```
git stash branch temp-branch stash@{2}
git status
git commit     # optional: use if desired to save index before adding
git add ...    # add all files as needed
git commit     # make the commit
```

Now go back to the branch you *were* on and use `git merge` or `git cherry-pick` or whatever you like to work with the *commit* at the tip of `temp-branch`.  The `-X` options are now available.

Note that `git stash branch` will have run `git stash drop stash@{2}`.  That's OK because now you have a whole *branch*, named `temp-branch` (or any other name of your choice).

(You can do this, sort of, carefully, with `git cherry-pick` directly on `stash@{2}`, but it's hard and painful; the `git stash branch` method is a bit klunky, but painless.  If you really want to do it directly, remember that this is reflog entry #2 of `refs/stash`, and the stash commit for `w` takes the form of a merge, with first-parent being the commit from which the "stash bag" depends.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem once, and I didn't find any option to `git-stash` to ignore whitespaces. But `git-apply` does have it. So what I did was:

```
$ git stash show --patch stash@{2} | git apply --ignore-whitespace
```

And then optionally, `git stash drop` to delete the stash.

Comment: I tried that and got errors saying `patch failed` and `patch does not apply`.

Comment: @EliasZamaria: yes, this only works if the patch applies without needing the full merge stuff.

Comment: @EliasZamaria: Can you try the `git apply` with the `-3` option?